# Sitecore 8.1 start rebuilding all indexes when ever I build the solution

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

I am using Sitecore 8.1 and whenever I build the solution. Sitecore starts rebuilding all the indexes when I load the website in browser. I am using IIS (localhost) on the development machine. Even if I change a some thing in web.config and reload the website (in browser), sitecore starts rebuilding indexes again.

Is it normal behavior with Sitcore 8.1? I have recently started working with it. I never had this kind of problem with Sitecore 7.2.

Comment: What do you mean by "making all the indexes"?

Comment: @KnowledgeOverflow How do you know that indexes are rebuilding? from the logs?

Comment: @AhmedOkour Yes, I have checked in Crawling.log.

Answer (score 0):

When you update web.config, Sitecore initiated a shutdown and restart again, once Sitecore gets restarted, it will start updating the indexes (I can see this in the crawling log).

IntervalAsynchronous strategy will be triggered and responsible for this behaviour.

> The strategy forces a full index rebuild when the number of entries in
>   the history table exceeds the number you specify in the
>   Indexing.FullRebuildItemCountThreshold setting. This normally means
>   that a substantial publishing or deployment has taken place, and this
>   should always trigger a full index rebuild.

Refer to this link for more information: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/index_update_strategies